# Conditional React render unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write some unit tests on React + Redux with Jest and Enzyme.

I'm kinda stuck on how I can write unit tests in a conditional rendering container.

```
...
 const {loading} = this.props

    if (loading) {
        return(
            <LoadingModal
              //Loading content
            />
        )
    }

    return(<div>//Regular APP</div>)
...
```

I'm already tested some regular render stuff, but right now I have to test some "loading content"

On my test file, I'm trying to update the store content to `{loading: false}` since the reducer initial state is `{loading: true}`, but I did not make it.

I'm also using redux-mock-store to try mock the store, as indicated on the following links but no progress was made.

https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store/issues/85
and
[Redux How to update the store in unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642041/redux-how-to-update-the-store-in-unit-tests)

my test file looks something like that:

```
describe('render', ()=>{

    beforeEach(()=>{
        ...
    })

    it('Loading rendered',()=>{
        expect(wrapped.find(LoadingModal).length).toEqual(1)
    })
})
```

If you guys need more information, please let me know,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your component gets `loading` from its props, you could just pass that in in your tests: `const wrapped = mount/shallow(<ComponentName loading={true} />)`

Comment: My props come from:


`const mapStateToProps = state => ({   
    loading: state.planets.loading
})`

Even when I pass:


`wrapped = mount(
            <Root>
                <App loading = {false}/>
            </Root>
        )`

My App continue to render only the loading version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm read a lot about this issue, and ultimately this follow piece of code resolve my problem.

Please, if you guys find some better way to do it, let me know.

```
import configureMockStore           from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk                        from 'redux-thunk'
import {Provider}                   from 'react-redux';
```

...

```
let wrapped

describe('render loading', () =>{

    const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])

    const store = mockStore({
        loading: true
    })

    beforeEach(()=>{
        wrapped = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App/>
            </Provider>
        )
    })

    it('rendered loading',()=>{
        expect(wrapped.find(LoadingModal).length).toEqual(1)
    })
  })
```